# Can anyone suggest me that below if condition is wrong or not?

Tags: android, string, null, equals

May occur any exception in coding for checking string is null or not ? Please help.

```
String code ;

if (!code.equals(null)) {

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: why dont you try it out? If already tried, provide the error or exception raised.

Comment: Condition should be `if(code != null)`

Comment: yes i tried there is no exception but this syntax is acceptable in coding standard or not?

Comment: Some time we get null as a String from API response then you have to write condition like `if(!code.equals("null"))`

Comment: @ChiragSavsani yes your condition is right but can't I used this insted of you suggest

Comment: @ChiragSavsani if i dont have any api calling then its acceptable or not?

Comment: @RavinaBhavsar you can check this way `code != null` and second one `!code.isEmpty()`..

Comment: @Ironman oky thankyou

Comment: @RavinaBhavsar I checked this code, This condition will work if code is not null, If code is null then this will throw `NullPointerException` .

Comment: @RavinaBhavsar this Exception will raised if code is null ` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @ChiragSavsani oky thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can check if String value is null or not

```
if(code != null){

}else{

}
```

You can not us `!code.equals(null)` because, `equals` is used to compare same **object** type. `null` is not any object type and **code** is `String`. If you consider null as `String`, then you can use `!code.equals("null")`

Comment: yes i knew this but can you explain why cant i used above if no api calling in my code?

Comment: ok thank you for details

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "object type", but `null` is a reference type, and it's perfectly "legal" to use as a parameter to `equals`, it's just useless is all.

Answer (score 0):

**String can be checked like this:**

```
if(code.equals("null") || code.equals("")) {
     // code to do when string is null.
 }
else {
     // code to do when string is not null.
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you will get no exception if `code` is `null`.

Comment: try it and check by your self

Comment: See @4castle answer and try to figure it out

Comment: String can check like this

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` is use to check the similarity of two `String`, and `==` or `!=` is use to check the condition. In your case you are checking the similarity of string.

```
if (!code.equals(null)) {
//code checks that String code is equal to null or not
}
else
{ 
}
```

another

```
if (code != null) {
//code checks if code is not equals to null (condition checking)
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if String is empty in Java, but what is the right way of doing it? right in the sense of robustness, performance and readability.  If robustness is your priority then using equals() method or Apache commons StringUtils is the right way to do this check. If you don't want to use third party library and happy of doing null check by yourself, then checking String's length is the fastest way and using isEmpty() method from String is most readable way. By the way,  don't confuse between empty and null String, if your application treat them same, then you can consider them same otherwise they are different, as null may not be classified as empty.  Here are three examples of checking String is empty or not by using JDK library itself.

[Read more Here](http://www.java67.com/2014/09/right-way-to-check-if-string-is-empty.html#ixzz4KCbDoUKe)

Comment: ok good will read it

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.equals(null)` to make a null check, because the API description for [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) states that:

> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Not only would this be a useless check (since it always returns `false`), it would also throw a `NullPointerException` if `code` actually was `null`, because a `null` value does not define an `equals` method.

```
Object x = null;
boolean isNull = x.equals(null); // NullPointerException on .equals
```

The only practical way to do a null check is to use:

```
if (code != null) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether string is empty i.e. `null` or `""` then use

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(code)){

}else{

}
```

`equals` checks the value exists in string.